# Specific Pattern Matching in Oracle

Tags: oracle, pattern-matching

I have a close to 1000 records which have first two characters as alphabets and then an number of characters.
eg.

```
 - BE123
 - QT12124
 - ST1000
 - XY12345
```

and similar data....
I have a table X in Oracle having a column 'Serial Number'  which will be having similar data , but it is of standard length 7 and also start with first two characters as alphabets.
I want to do a pattern matching on the column Serial Number where i can use `LIKE` and '%' matching on the characters after first two characters in the column  for eg 
if the column has a data

```
 - BE00123 , it should start give me BE123 as matched data
 - QT12124 , it is matched data
 - ST11001 , unmatched data
 - XY12345, matched data
```

Comment: I don't understand your rules for what is a match and what is not.  Can you explain that better?

Comment: lets take BE123 as example ,
so these are the following criteria for search

Comment: 1. The first two alphabets should be matched without any condition , 
2. since the number of characters in the column in table is 7  and the search string is 5 then it is possible that  between BE and 123 , 2 characters have been missed
BE00123 would be a valid match , 
BE57123 would be valid match  
BE12300 would be a valid match
BUT BE12003 would not be valid match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this returns what you asked. See if it helps.

```
SQL> with t_one (col) as
  2    (select 'BE123'   from dual union all
  3     select 'QT12124' from dual union all
  4     select 'ST1000'  from dual union all
  5     select 'XY12345' from dual
  6    ),
  7    t_two (col) as
  8    (select 'BE00123' from dual union all
  9     select 'QT12124' from dual union all
 10     select 'ST11001' from dual union all
 11     select 'XY12345' from dual
 12    )
 13  select o.col
 14  from t_one o join t_two t on substr(o.col, 1, 2) = substr(t.col, 1, 2)
 15                           and instr(t.col, substr(o.col, 3)) > 0;

COL
-------
BE123
QT12124
XY12345

SQL>
```

- Line 14: match first two characters
- Line 15: check whether characters from T_ONE table, starting from position 3, are contained in the T_TWO table's column value

Comment: So ,in this ,the data to be searched is in excel and need to be taken in Oracle .
And the data with which the pattern has to be matched is in a column 'SerialNumber' in Table X.
I dont think there is a scope of applying union

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. OK, first you have to import data from Excel file to an Oracle table. Everything is then in the database so ... apply the above query, using real table and column names. I used CTE to simulate test case you wrote. What do you mean by the last sentence, "scope of applying union"? Which *union*?